# How to convert Date String (8 august 2012) to number format( 08 08 2012)?

Tags: php

hi how to convert the string format date to number format ?

```
$bd=$row[dateofb];
o/p:08 august 2012
```

But how to convert the above sting to 08/08/1212

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this. The `date` function in conjunction with `strtotime` :)

```
echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($bd));
```